# jquery show slide bug

Tags: jquery, show, slide

The desired effect is for the panel to change depending on which #button you click on.  This works fine.  The only problem I have noticed is that no matter what #button you click, the settings panel is the one that slides by.  I tried to have a global var and store the prev panel, but that was not working at all.  I believe the problem lies in this line

```
$("div#text div").not("#"+target).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
```

Thanks!

CSS

```
#buttons {float:left;}
#buttons ul {list-style-type:none;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;}
#buttons ul  li {height:195px;width:40px;float:left}
#buttons a {display:block;height:195px;width:40px;border:none;cursor:pointer;}
#buttons a.settings:hover, #buttons a.messages:hover, #buttons a.payments:hover {background-position: -40px 0;}
#buttons a.settings {background:url(accountsettings.png)}
#buttons a.messages {background:url(accountmessages.png)}
#buttons a.payments {background:url(accountpayments.png)}
#buttons a.panel-selected {background-position: -40px 0;}

#text{width:550px;height:199px;overflow:hidden;float:left;}
div#text div {width:550px;height:199px;float:left; margin-left:20px;}
div#text div h3 {font-family:Georgia, garamond, serif;font-size:1.8em;color:#092a43;font-weight:lighter;}
div#text div ul {list-style-type:none;float:left;}
div#text div ul li {height:195px;width:175px;float:left;padding:10px 0 0 0;}
div#text div ul li p {font-size:1.2em;color:#27608b;padding:10px 0 0 0;line-height:1.4em;}
div#text div ul li a {font-size:1.6em;padding:20px 0 0 0;}

div#settings div{ width:120px;height:140px;float:left;}
div#messages div{ width:120px;height:140px;float:left;}
div#payments div{ width:120px;height:140px;float:left;}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="buttons">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="settings"></a></li>
            <li><a class="messages"></a></li>
            <li><a class="payments"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="text">
       <div id="settings">
          <h3>Account Settings</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
                <p>test1</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="messages">
          <h3>Messages</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
                <p>test2</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="payments">
          <h3>Payments</h3>
            <li>
                <p>test3</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
       </div>          
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $("div#text div:not(#settings)").hide();
    $("#buttons li a.settings").addClass("panel-selected");

    $("#buttons li a").click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("panel-selected") == false){
            var target = $(this).attr("class");
            $("#buttons li a:not(a." + target + ")").removeClass("panel-selected");
            $(this).addClass("panel-selected");
            $("#"+target).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);

            $("div#text div").not("#"+target).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct.  The line:

```
$("div#text div").not("#"+target).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
```

is selecting the two divs in #text that aren't the target, which may be causing the problem.  You may want to store the current div in a variable to avoid that:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$("div#text div:not(#settings)").hide();
$("#buttons li a.settings").addClass("panel-selected");

var current_div;
$("#buttons li a").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("panel-selected") == false){
        var target = $(this).attr("class");
        $("#buttons li a:not(a." + target + ")").removeClass("panel-selected");
        $(this).addClass("panel-selected");
        var next_div = $('#'+target);
        next_div.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);

        if (current_div) {
            current_div.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
        }
        current_div = next_div;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just had to make one small change
    var current_div = $('#settings');
since I select the settings button on load